# How do I install ConTeXt alongside MikTeX

Tags: installing, context, windows

I would like to give ConTeXt a shot. It is likely just me, but I am finding the installation guide on the wiki a little confusing, e.g.

- Do I need Ruby or not?  Does that depend on the installer, current TeX distribution, anything else?
- Does the (one of the) GUI installers work?  What is the difference between that and the command line installer?
- If I install alongside a working TeX distribution, do I want the environment variables set globally or not?  Why?  Why not?
- Do I use `texexec.exe/rb`?  Do I use `context.exe`?

Some of the above questions, I *think* I know the answer to, but I'm not sure.  Ideally, I would like to set up a TeXnicCenter output profile to build and view a ConTeXt file.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Do I need Ruby or not?

There are two versions of ConTeXt in use, MkII and MkIV. MkII uses `texexec`,
Ruby and pdfTeX (or XeTeX) and is the frozen stable version. MkIV does not
need Ruby, it is launched using `context` and uses LuaTeX as backend. This is
the current development version.

If you don't have a good reason to use MkII I would advice to go for MkIV and
not care about MkII.

> Does that depend on the installer, current tex distribution, anything else?

If Ruby is installed, by default both versions, MkII and MkIV are installed. If
Ruby is not present only MkIV can be used.

> Does the (one of the) GUI installers work? What is the difference between that and the command line installer?

I never used a GUI installer. I would suggest to just try if it works. It
should install the same distribution, ConTeXt standalone. In any case the
command line install (using `first-setup`) is the preferred and supported
method which should work in any case. You'll get a better experience if you
also install the [optional helper
programs](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone#Dependencies), but
that's optional.

> If I install alongside a working tex distribution, do I want the environment variables set globally or not? Why? Why not?

This depends on your workflow and personal preference and how you launch TeX.
If you prefer to launch it from the command line or from an editor. If you
mainly use MikTeX, you might want to have MikTeX in you PATH and not ConTeXt
standalone. I personally have the ConTeXt standalone beta in my PATH by
default. If I use older versions which are local to a project, I set up the
PATH locally for that shell or within that editor session.

> Do I use texexec.exe/rb? Do I use context.exe?

`texexec` launches MkII, `context` launches MkIV. As described above, you
probalbly don't need to care about `texexec`. In the older documentation the
examples using `texexec` can be replaced by `context`.

Comment: A minor correction. Both `texexec.exe` and `context.exe` can use any engine by specifying `--pdftex`, `--xetex`, or `--luatex`. `context.exe` defaults to `--luatex` while `texexec.exe` defaults to `--pdftex`.

Comment: You're totally right. But that might confuse the OP even more. I think it's easier to just stick to `context` and forget about `texexec`.

Comment: Thanks Marco, I launch `TeX` through my editor and would like to continue to do that.  I would also like to launch `ConTeXt` through my editor.  The information [here](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/TeXnicCenter) was what confused me about the need for `Ruby` as it suggests that I need it.  Do you know whether that information is outdated/incorrect?